# Laravel 5.2 query to find how many times a tag/string used in a Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've 2 tables. 1 articles table and 1 tags table. I need to find out how many times a tag is being used in all articles in article table.
Currently I'm using the below codes to get it. But its slower process. Is there any better way or laravel query to make it faster?

```
    $tags = Tag::get();

    $array = array();

    foreach($tags as $tag){
        $articles = count(Article::where('public', '1')->where('tags', 'rlike', $tag->tag)->get());
        if ($articles > 0) {
            $array[] = array(
                    $tag->tag => $articles
                );
        }
    }

    return json_encode($aaa);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rearrange your relationships as proposed by @manniL or simply do a raw query which is very fast:

```
$result = DB::table('tags')
->leftjoin('articles', 'articles.tags', 'rlike', 'tags.name')
->selectRaw('tags.name, count(articles.id) as total')
->groupBy('tags.name')
->get();
```

This will return something like

```
[
    {'name': 'tag1', 'total': 3},
    {'name': 'tag2', 'total': 2},
    {'name': 'tag3', 'total': 7}
]
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that you have a Many-To-Many relation, but no normalized tables therefore. I'd suggest to adapt the database tables, because then you just could to `$tag->articles()->count()` to get the amount of articles where a specific `$tag` is used without loading the items.

A great structure would be:

```
articles (Table for your articles)

id
public
...

tags (Tag data table)

id
name
...

articles_tags (Pivot table)

article_id
tag_id
```

There is also a [great chapter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) in the documentations about many to many relations.